# Question about tree-shaking / side-effects

Tags: javascript, webpack, tree-shaking

I am trying to reduce bundle size of my nextjs project and I have some problem with tree shaking.
Let me explain.
I have a Flags.js file that export multiple flags component :

```
export { default as FlagsCn } from './FlagsCn';
export { default as FlagsDe } from './FlagsDe';
export { default as FlagsEsCt } from './FlagsEsCt';
export { default as FlagsEs } from './FlagsEs';
export { default as FlagsFr } from './FlagsFr';
export { default as FlagsGb } from './FlagsGb';
export { default as FlagsGr } from './FlagsGr';
export { default as FlagsIt } from './FlagsIt';
export { default as FlagsJp } from './FlagsJp';
export { default as FlagsNo } from './FlagsNo';
export { default as FlagsPh } from './FlagsPh';
export { default as FlagsPt } from './FlagsPt';
export { default as FlagsRu } from './FlagsRu';
export { default as FlagsTh } from './FlagsTh';
export { default as FlagsBg } from './FlagsBg';
```

Then I import only two flags into my other component :

```
import { FlagsFr, FlagsGb } from '@components/Flags';
```

But I noticed that all Flags are imported when I take a look into the bundle with webpack-bundle-analyzer.
If I apply sideEffects to false into the package.json, the js bundle file size reduce by 400kb but I've got some strange error during the navigation. I think it means that some library are causing side effects.

So what should I do ?
Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Visit all the modules that were dropped and inspect their top-level statements?

Comment: You need to find out what code has side effects and supply an array to sideEffects which lists those modules.  see the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason could be that you have not set `mode: 'production'` in webpack.config.js.

Additionally, if you don't need all the flags simultaneously then consider code splitting. It can be done by:

- using [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)
- having [multiple React SPAs](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react#react-application-splitting)

Comment: You suggest "multiple Reat SPAs" - React is not referenced anywhere in the question.

Comment: @EuanSmith True. This particular suggestion in based on assumption that React is used and can be safely ignored if it is not.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @winwiz1 !
Production mode is correctly set and flags are not used in the project for now so I don't need them into the final bundle, even if they are in seperate js file with dynamic import.
Between I'm using nextjs/babel/react.
Babel doesn't have any commonjs transform plugin set also (I know that it can break tree-shaking